# Finding delay of circuits

Tags: delay, logic-gates

I have an AND gate having two input.

1st input is constant 0 and
2nd input is circuit x .

Now suppose the AND gate has p second delay and circuit has q second delay.

Then what will be the delay of whole circuit?

Will it be

p ? or p+q ?

Answer (score 2):

One input of the AND gate is connected to constant 0. So the output will always be zero. Input has no effect on output. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_delay):

> *"In electronics, digital circuits and digital electronics, the
>   propagation delay, or gate delay, is the length of time which starts
>   when the input to a logic gate becomes stable and valid to change, to
>   the time that the output of that logic gate is stable and valid to
>   change."*

So I guess the delay would be 0 in your case.

If 1st input to AND gate was not 0, then the delay = p+q.

Comment: What is meant by '.. valid to change'?

Comment: @sherrellbc The stable state the input/output reached is a valid one. that is what I understood. But I am not a native speaker of English. :)